# A simple thread-safe Deque in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, deque

I am trying to implement a thread-safe deque in C++.
`ThreadSafeDeque` will be used by a `FileLogger` class.
When threads call the `log()` function of `FileLogger` the messages will be `push_back()`ed to `ThreadSafeDeque` and return almost immediately. In a separate thread the FileLogger will `pop_front()` messages and write them to a file in its own pace.

Am I doing things correctly and efficient below?

```
#pragma once
#include <deque>
#include <mutex>
template<class T>
class ThreadSafeDeque {
public:
    void pop_front_waiting(T &t) {
        // unique_lock can be unlocked, lock_guard can not
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ mutex }; // locks
        while(deque.empty()) {
            condition.wait(lock); // unlocks, sleeps and relocks when woken up  
        }
        t = deque.front();
        deque.pop_front();
    } // unlocks as goes out of scope

    void push_back(const T &t) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ mutex }; 
        deque.push_back(t);
        lock.unlock();
        condition.notify_one(); // wakes up pop_front_waiting  
    }
private:
    std::deque<T>               deque;
    std::mutex                  mutex;
    std::condition_variable condition;
};
```

Comment: The use case you present calls for a *queue*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's probably worth accepting a second template argument for an Allocator to be passed through to the `std::deque`:

```
template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class ThreadSafeDeque {
    std::deque<T, Allocator> deque;
};
```

Technically, we do need to include `<condition_variable>`; we're not allowed to assume that `<mutex>` always pulls it in.

I don't like the interface to `pop_front_waiting()` - why does the caller have to pass an lvalue reference, instead of simply being returned the value?  Return-value optimisation will ensure there's no unnecessary copy.

The locking logic all looks good to me.  We can avoid the `lock.unlock()` by using a simple lock-guard with smaller scope:

```
void push_back(const T &t)
{
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ mutex }; 
        deque.push_back(t);
    }
    condition.notify_one(); // wakes up pop_front_waiting  
}
```

From C++17, we can use constructor deduction and omit the template parameter from `std::lock_guard` and `std::unique_lock`, making the code a little easier to read.

It's helpful to show that members are intentionally default-constructed, and it pacifies `g++ -Weffc++`:

```
std::deque<T> deque = {};
std::mutex mutex = {};
std::condition_variable condition = {};
```

Comment: The `pop_front_waiting` interface is necessary to provide exception safety with types that are not nothrow movable. Named return value optimization is not guaranteed, so there may be a move construction into the return value that could throw, in which case the object would already be removed from the queue and lost.

Comment: Arguably move constructors shouldn't throw though, so a `static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T>)` test might be preferable to using the weird interface.

Comment: Where would there be a non-guaranteed copy elision?  AFAICS, that would only be possible in old (pre-C++17) platforms.  Problems would be endemic if `T` could throw when moved, as `std::deque` is allowed to move elements (e.g. in `shrink_to_fit()`).  As walnut says, probably better to avoid accepting such types.

Comment: Copy elision in a return statement was made mandatory only from prvalues, not from operands naming local variables and you need an intermediate variable to store the copy from `deque.front()`. See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). `deque::shrink_to_fit()` does not have strong exception safety guarantees if the move constructor throws, but all the modifiers at the beginning and end of the `deque` are guaranteed to have no effect if any exceptions at all are thrown, see [\[deque.modifiers\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/deque.modifiers).

Comment: So if the interface was kept the way OP has it, the class would work with strong exception guarantee on both member functions, even with non-nothrow movable types.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers cover a lot but I also would suggest replacing

```
while(deque.empty()) {
    condition.wait(lock); // unlocks, sleeps and relocks when woken up  
}
```

with

```
condition.wait(lock, [this]{return !deque.empty();});
```

because it means the same and is more compact (readability being the same or also better).

Comment: Why would you suggest this change? What improvements does it bring? Can you [edit] your answer to describe the rationale?